# $http.success callback not being called on IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have an AngularJS application that loads some data using $http service, then based on the revised data it updates corresponding html elements and updates the UI. Here is the code:

```
app.controller("RankingCtrl", function ($scope, PostModel, DeserializePosts, $http, $cookies){
    var mainContainer = $('#mainContainer');

    $scope.error = null;
    function loadTop(){
        $http({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/ranking',
            headers: {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHTTPRequest',
            }
        }).success(function(topPosts){
            var mostLikedPosts = DeserializePosts(topPosts.mostLiked);
            var mostViewedPosts = DeserializePosts(topPosts.mostViewed);
            var mostCommentedPosts = DeserializePosts(topPosts.mostCommented);

            $scope.topLiked = mostLikedPosts;
            $scope.topViewed = mostViewedPosts;
            $scope.topCommented = mostCommentedPosts;
        }).error(function(error){
            errorHandler(error.statusCode, error);
        }).finally(function () {
            $('#mainContainerSpinner').hide();
            mainContainer.fadeIn();
        });
    }
    loadTop();
});
```

My problem is, apparently the .success function is not being called, since the .finally function does get executed but the UI is not updates with any of the downloaded elements. If I ctrl-R the IE browser window, then the function works properly and the UI shows the expected elements. This issue does not happen on Chrome or FireFox.

Interestingly, when I open the F12 dev tools from IE to debug this JS code, the issue does not happen. Looks more like a bug on IE11 but I was wondering if anyone else has seen this behavior and if there are workarounds to try. Currently, my users need to refresh the page when they visit it, as only a page refresh updated the UI as expected on this AngularJS controller.

UPDATE: the UI is not getting updated because the .success function has a `forEach` instruction that is throwing an exception. This is happening because the browser is sending the $http request **without** the 'X-Requested-With' header that is specified in the code above, so the response it receives is html instead of json. Forcing a browser refresh does make the browser add this header to the http request.

Comment: Did you try to use `cache` option of $http config?

Comment: @yazaki, nothing done explicitly with cache. Why? Should I look into adding some changes there?

Comment: Hi @Luis!
Judging from the situation where your problem occurs (only IE, not occur with opening IE devtool). It has been often that browser cache is related with these problems in my experiences.

BTW I read your update. 
To organize your problem, I understood that $http doesn't set headers 'X-Requested-With' only with IE(not opening devtool).
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: When I tried similar code, my IE11(11.0.9600.17691) is always sending headers as expected.

The following is completely different point, `type: 'GET'` is jsut misspelled? I think `method: 'GET'` is correct.